# Finding moves with multiple jumps in checkers

Tags: ai, turn-based

I'm currently working on a minimax implementation for a game of checkers in C#. The minimax itself works fine if you ignore a few bugs I've yet to fix, but I'm having some problems finding a way I can properly create lists of 'Chain' moves, or moves with multiple jumps.

I've made several attempts at building a function which would take an attacking move and run it through some recursion to find all the possible branches, but so far the main result is that no attack move at all has been working.

Anyhow I'd appreciate some pointers on how to go about generating all the attack moves that could follow as a result of an attack. I'm guessing some form of recursion is going to be necessary at the very least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each time you find a jump check on the resulting board if that piece can jump again

this is easiest if you can clone a board state (or restore it again after the recursion)

basic code to find longest jump chain (easily adapted to find all jumps)

```
maxjumps;
foreach(piece: board){
    if piece.color = currentplayer
        jumps = canAttack(piece,board)
        if jumps.count>maxjump.count
            maxjump = jumps
}
```

and canAttack will be:

```
maxjumps;
foreach(move: piece.attackingMoves){
    if board.isValid(move)
        tmpboard = board.clone
        tmpboard.domove(move)
        jumps = move.concatJumps(canattack(move.resultpiece,tmpboard))
        if jumps.count>maxjump.count
            maxjump = jumps
}
return maxjumps
```

if you don't want to clone the board you do a `undomove` on the board right after the `canattack` call

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done the trick, though there are still some issues because I'm retarded.
Also I'll advise against cloning since last time I tried that it took up nearly all the memory on the computer storing the board.

Comment: unless you have a good pooling or garbage collection undoing is indeed better

Comment: Undoing always gives you a lot better performance, as it can use the L1 cache of the CPU (or maybe C# even uses registers in some cases?). I implemented a chess engine, which was -really- slow because of "cloning". A do/undo strategy is much faster... but for checkers this might be less an issue. It depends much on how you store your game state. If you just use a bitfield (e.g. use the class "BitArray"), cloning should be quite fast. But what ever you do, try to keep your board on the stack (=local variables, not initialized via "new Classname()").